# How can I mount an EFS volume onto an Elastic Beanstalk docker application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a small docker-compose app in Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk. I need some persistent storage, so I've decided to try EFS.

I'm trying to follow some instructions on [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-mount-efs-volumes/), which despite being written in 2017 links to an example for a configuration file which can be pasted in as `.ebextenssions/mount.config`.

I understand that this problem could be an incompatibility between the EFS mounting code (which only supports Amazon Linux 1) and the Elastic Beanstalk Docker platform, which only supports Amazon Linux 2.

So how am I supposed to get past this? I want Docker and Elastic File Store!

Whenever I start the application, I get this error message in eb-engine.log:

```
2022/10/14 16:13:38.516728 [INFO] Error occurred during build: Command 01_mount failed
2022/10/14 16:13:38.517386 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PreBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: EbExtension build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.
```

In cfn-init.log I get:

```
2022-10-14 16:12:33,873 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2022-10-14 16:12:33,879 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2022-10-14 16:12:33,882 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2022-10-14 16:12:33,893 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_hartree_scf
2022-10-14 16:12:51,528 [INFO] Yum installed ['amazon-efs-utils']
2022-10-14 16:13:38,486 [ERROR] Command 01_mount (/tmp/mount-efs.sh) failed
2022-10-14 16:13:38,486 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_hartree_scf: Command 01_mount failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_mount failed
2022-10-14 16:13:38,489 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2022-10-14 16:13:38,489 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_mount failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 564, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_mount failed
```

This is an Amazon Linux 2 instance:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-20 log]$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 4.14.291-218.527.amzn2.x86_64 (mockbuild@ip-10-0-39-162) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13) (GCC)) #1 SMP Fri Aug 26 09:54:31 UTC 2022
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-20 log]$ hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: ip-172-31-24-20.eu-west-1.compute.internal
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: ec2444d94202d8a938217171503e4d1d
           Boot ID: 8b6a6dceeee6459a8404c761d336bba0
    Virtualization: xen
  Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
       CPE OS Name: cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2
            Kernel: Linux 4.14.291-218.527.amzn2.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-20 log]$
```

The odd thing is when I delete the .ebextensions folder and I redeploy, I still seem to get the same error. Why does this keep happening? Why would the `/tmp/mount-efs.sh` file still exist if it's no longer part of the configuration?